# Calling maven goal from within another goal

Tags: dependency-injection, maven, plexus

I'm trying to create a wrapper to a maven plugin that I found in the internet.
My wrapper should do some work than call the execute on the original plugin's goal.

The examples I saw so far instantiate the other plugin, set all the variables, than call the execute method. I don't want to do this (if I can avoid it) because most of the instance variables are private.

Is there some way to make plexus inject an instance of the other plugin while populating the instance variables? Maven documentation is very vague about this... couldn't make it work.

Thanks,
Rafael.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish with all this.  With Maven there are often many ways of reaching the same objective.

Comment: Ok, I want to do a plugin, but I want to make this plugin do somethings then pass control to another plugin.
In spring, for example, I would inject the other bean inside my bean and call the method I want. Spring would handle the initialization of the variables that are inject in the bean I am calling.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`MojoExecutor`](http://trac.qulice.com/qulice/browser/qulice/tags/qulice-0.2.2/qulice/qulice-maven-plugin/src/main/java/com/qulice/maven/MojoExecutor.java) class from [qulice-maven-plugin](http://www.qulice.com/qulice-maven-plugin/index.html). The class does exactly what you're looking for, e.g.:

```
new MojoExecutor(mavenPluginManager, mavenSession)
  .execute("com.qulice:maven-qulice-plugin:1.0", "check", properties);
```